# How to fix putting JS made HTML element into the actual HTML body?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to loop an array and put all row titles as a seperate header in my HTML body.  Creating **P** tags and appending it works, but now I made a whole html element and want to append that into the body, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    //var para = document.createElement("P"); 
    //para.innerText = rows[i].titel;
    //document.body.appendChild(para);

    var titel = rows[i].titel;
    var post = "<div class='card-body'>\
                <h5 class='card-title'>"+ titel + "</h5>\
                <a href='oefeningDetail.html' class='btn btn-primary'>details</a>\
                </div>";

    console.log(post);
    document.body.appendChild(post);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the **appendChild()** function expects a html element as it's parameter - you're trying to pass a string.

You can use the **.innerHTML** property instead.

```
  var post = "<div class='card-body'>\
                            <h5 class='card-title'>" + titel + "</h5>\
                            <a href='oefeningDetail.html' class='btn btn-primary'>details</a>\
                            </div>";
  document.body.innerHTML = post;
```

Comment: This is correct, however I'd suggest to use `appendChild()` and swap string with `document.createElement()` generated stuff, especially if `titel` is something users can input.

Answer (score 0):

As @obscure mentioned, the reason that this isn't working is because `appendChild()` expects a `node` type parameter value in order to work.  He provided an alternative with the `innerHTML` attribute, but, as @Walk mentioned in the comments, there are some added security risks with that, so the `appendChild()` approach may still be the best option.

Given that you are lopping through and adding multiple elements, it may be easiest to create a single element "template" and clone it in your loop:

```
// Create "card-body" template
var elementTemplate = document.createElement("div");
elementTemplate.setAttribute("class", "card-body");

// Create "card-title" template
var headerTemplate = document.createElement("h5");
headerTemplate.setAttribute("class", "card-title");

// Create button template
var linkTemplate = document.createElement("a");
linkTemplate.setAttribute("href", "oefeningDetail.html");
linkTemplate.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-primary");
linkTemplate.textContent = "details";

// Append "card-title" and button to the "card-body" template
elementTemplate.appendChild(headerTemplate);
elementTemplate.appendChild(linkTemplate);

// Now that you have a template to work with . . .

// Loop through the rows
for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    // Create local deep copy of the "card-body" template
    var newElement = elementTemplate.cloneNode(true);

    // Update the "card-title" header in the new element with the "titel" value
    newElement.querySelector(".card-title").textContent = rows[i].titel;

    // Append the new element to the body
    document.body.appendChild(newElement);
}
```